# Opencart Admin Data Scraping

Tags: php, web-scraping, opencart, screen-scraping

Hi i have been trying to do data scraping of all orders from order_id=1 to order_id=10 in opencart with this code

[http://www.myopencartstore.com/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&token=97d9e2f96bb321a6f3506834d6f082e7&order_id=1](http://myopencartstore.com/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&token=97d9e2f96bb321a6f3506834d6f082e7&order_id=1)

```
   <?php
    $url = 'http://www.myopencartstore.com/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&token=97d9e2f96bb321a6f3506834d6f082e7&order_id=1';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $first_step = explode( '<div class="llst-item-address">' , $content );
    $second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[0] );

    print_r ($second_step);
    ?>
```

but it seens that opencart admin just automatically loggs me out and i also tried

```
https://import.io/ a web scrapping tool
```

it works for all websites with query string but when i use it with OPENCART ADMIN it just loggs me out i know you can do this with the database but the store owner told me to do it like this can you help

Comment: You need cookie support, which generally means using curl instead of file_get_contents

Comment: @user574632 how do i do it

Comment: It's ridiculous to do it like this when you can do it with the database

Comment: @JayGilford Ha i know but its we website owner that wants me to do it do you know how to do it like that

Comment: Looks like another case of *my client want it that way so I do it that way without thinking* and also *I am a total noob but I have so many clients so why not*. Happens more and more often these days. Maybe some disease? Hopefully I won't get infected by it...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP requests a stupid (I am sorry, it's true, it's no rude nor offense!) solution when there is a direct and easy approach. He refuses to do what's natural and who goes against nature goes against himself in the end. No help possible.

Comment: @shadyyx thats true but still there has to be another solution

Answer (score 1):

You could just query Opencart's database (place this php file in the root of your store, where the config.php is - it's just required for the database connection details, so you don't have to enter the details manually):

```
require("config.php");

$db = new MySQLi(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order WHERE order_id BETWEEN 1 AND 10");
echo "<pre>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  print_r($row);
}
echo "</pre>";
$result->free();
$db->close();
```

Comment: i know that but i want to do it this way

Comment: But this is just faster, and easier to handle the data received. Well, it's up to you...

Comment: Ha i know but its we website owner that wants me to do it do you know how to do it like that

Comment: ... try to convince the website's owner that this is a much better solution. There's no reason to do it in another way. The only reason is: You don't have FTP access to the website, and you haven't received permission from the site's owner. Come on... Opencart is a database driven application, so don't try to reinvent the wheel with this web-scaping idea.

Comment: i know that already what can i do he just wants me to do that.

Comment: *i know that already what can i do he just wants me to do that* - **to do what exactly?** *i know that but i want to do it this way* - **then we cannot help you**, sorry.